# setOnLongClickListener not working with PinchImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I downloaded the android-pinch jar so that I can have zoom functionality. The problem I am having is that I have to do `setOnLongClickListener` because I want to create a DragShadow for the user to see when they are dragging an icon or image and I want to assign a `setOnClickListener` to the image. However the `PinchImageView` for some reason doesn't work with my single and long click listeners, nothing happens.

Here is the code( it's a custom adapter ):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    try
    {
        if(view == null)
            view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.tools_layout, viewGroup, false);

        PinchImageView img = (PinchImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setBackgroundResource(drawId[position]);
        img.setTag(icons.get(position));

        img.setLongClickable(true);

        img.setOnLongClickListener(longListen);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.i("customException", "getView():" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return view;
}

View.OnLongClickListener longListen = new View.OnLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {
            isListItem = true; // this never gets run...
            Log.i(TAG, "long click");
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadow dragShadow = new DragShadow(v);

            v.startDrag(data, dragShadow, v, 0);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.i("customException", "longListen: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

I've even tried changing the return to true because I saw in the `TouchImageView` that changing the return made it work, probably not the same for `PinchImageView` but was worth a try. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try entering the PinchImageView source code and change the top to:

```
implements OnTouchListener, View.OnLongClickListener
```

Then implement a callback to your code or do whatever you want.

Comment: I got rid of PinchImageView but I will try this later( was just taking too long for what I wanted to do )

Comment: You can look at this site, They have a good imageViews section http://android-arsenal.com/